# Nvidia drivers 515 depends on 525

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

A couple of days now Nvidia drivers 510 and 515 depends on (and installs) 525 (which contains CUDA 12).
In other words when I do `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515` it is like I install `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-525`.

How to install 515 from official repos, any thoughts?

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nvidia-driver-515

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to disable Ubuntu's *restricted* repo and add Nvidia's repos instead. See instructions bellow:

```
export DISTRO=ubuntu2004
export ARCH=x86_64
add-apt-repository -r restricted
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$DISTRO/$ARCH/cuda-$DISTRO-keyring.gpg
mv cuda-$DISTRO-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/cuda-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cuda-archive-keyring.gpg] https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$DISTRO/$ARCH/ /" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda-$DISTRO-$ARCH.list
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/$DISTRO/$ARCH/cuda-$DISTRO.pin
mv cuda-$DISTRO.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
apt update
apt install -y nvidia-driver-510
```

EDIT: more info here: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#network-repo-installation-for-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Note the current description on the nvidia-driver-515 Ubuntu 22.04 package:

> Description-en: Transitional package for nvidia-driver-525  This is a
> transitional package for nvidia-driver-525, and can be  safely removed
> after the installation is complete.

You get the 525 install, since it totally replaced the 515. If you really need obsolete drivers, Nvidia still has them, but using them will result in the usual update problems, every time you get a kernel update, and no working scripts to rebuild the 515 driver.